# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LoadJobConfig' - python import in BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to make an import in my Google BigQuery database via JSON on my Mac via the Terminal. When I'm trying to use the following code:

```
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_id = 'stock'

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
]
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.json"

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri,
    dataset_ref.table("us_states"),
    location="US",  # Location must match that of the destination dataset.
    job_config=job_config,
)  # API request
print("Starting job {}".format(load_job.job_id))

load_job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
print("Job finished.")

destination_table = client.get_table(dataset_ref.table("us_states"))
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

When I'm running the script I'm getting the following error:

```
line 6, in <module>
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LoadJobConfig'
```

Can you guys help me out? thanks a lot.

Comment: https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig that method is only available for the `job` type you are trying to access it wrong

Comment: I saw that your code is similar to the code in [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_json_data_into_a_new_table). I tried to replicate the same code and I didn't have any error message. I used the version 1.24.0 of the client. Is this the version that you are using?